# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree for Bottom-tabs

Tags: react-native, expo

i am trying to install react-navigation/bottom-tabs and i keep getting this following error

```
PS C:\Users\chuy\LaYa> npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: @react-navigation/native@5.9.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/native@"^5.9.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\chuy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chuy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-01T01_09_31_834Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This issue is related to the Expo version. I was unable to update the version, so I created a new project and moved everything there files.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.